# Remove an object's key and value using a variable from function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

Hey I'm trying to remove a key:value pair from state inside a Javascript Object.

It works when I hardcode the key name in the code, but when I try to use a variable from a function call, it does nothing.

Can somebody help me out?

Here's an object example:

```
  toppingsSelected: {
     "Onion":"true",
     "Mushrooms":"true",
  }
```

This works, hardcoded:

```
deleteTopping = toppingName => {

   const { Onion, ...withoutOnion } = toppingsSelected;
   console.log(withoutOnion); // Returns object without onion

  };
```

This doesn't work:

```
deleteTopping = toppingName => {


   const toppingName = "Onion"; // Variable gets passed in

   const { toppingName, ...withoutOnion } = toppingsSelected;
   console.log(withoutOnion); // Returns original object, no change made

  };
```

So I'm basically trying to remove a key from React state but I'm pretty new to Javascript.

How can I make Javascript aware that toppingName is a key?

Comment: As far as I know you can't use dynamic keys while destructing. So, go for alternative provided answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option is to add square brackets arround `toppingName`, and assign it to a variable. As @Bergi pointed out in the comments, this option does not mutate `toppingsSelected`

```js
const toppingsSelected = {
  "Onion":"true",
  "Mushrooms":"true",
};
const toppingName = "Onion";
const {
  [toppingName]: topping,
  ...withoutOnion
} = toppingsSelected;

console.log(JSON.stringify(withoutOnion));
```

To set the React state, you'd then do this

```
this.setState({ toppingsSelected: withoutOnion })
```

Comment: Wow, what interesting way of doing this. The point is defining it as `undefined` I think.

Comment: `Onion` will be undefined in `withoutOnion` in this example

Comment: Yes I know but I can swear it, first I tried it with `undefined` instead of a random variable and it worked :) Now it does not work. Weird and again very interesting way.

Comment: This is the correct answer for my question about JS objects, but for some reason, though it makes the correct object mutation, React does not update it with setState.

Comment: Can you update your example with how you are using setState?

Comment: It works for me. `deleteTopping = toppingName => {
    const {
      [toppingName]: topping,
      ...withoutOnion
    } = this.state.toppingsSelected;
    this.setState({toppingsSelected: withoutOnion})
  }`

Comment: This works @devserkan - must be me confusing the JS syntax again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `delete` e.g.

```
delete toppingsSelected[toppingName];
```

Comment: That works! I tried that before but it didn't work. Must have been using wrong syntax,

Comment: Notice that this - unlike destructuring - will mutate `toppingsSelected`, which is probably a no-go for dealing with state.

Comment: Yes, if this method will be used it is better to do something like this: `const newToppingsSelected = { ...toppingsSelected };
delete newToppingsSelected[toppingName]; this.setState( { toppingsSelected: newToppingsSelected } )`

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is using [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
const _obj = {
  'Onion': true,
  'notOnion': false
};

const newObj = Object.keys(_obj)
  .filter(key => key !== 'Onion')
  .reduce((acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, cur }), {})

console.log(newObj); // { notOnion: false }
```

This will return a new object without the 'Onion' property